# In qt 4.5, is it possible to have resources in a statically linked plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a custom QT plugin module that has embedded resources.  I want to statically link this plugin with an application:

```
LIBS += -lstatic_plugin_with_resources
```

In the application I am using the `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN()` macro, which allows the application to use the plugin; however the plugin can not access its embedded resources.

Using the plugin as a shared library does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.  In the application you need to explicitly initialize the resources that are contained in the static plugin.

This is accomplished by calling the **`Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resource_base_name)`**, where `resource_base_name` is the base name of the .qrc file that specifies the resources. This should probably be called in main() or at application startup.  Optionally you can call **`Q_CLEANUP_RESOURCE()`** if the plugin is no longer being used.

See the last section of the QT 4.5 [resource doc](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/resources.html).  Also see the documentation for [`Q_INIT_RESOURCE`](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qdir.html#Q_INIT_RESOURCE).

This worked for me on the linux version of QT 4.5.